# Using `onBackpressureLatest` to drop intermediate messages in blocking Flowable

Tags: rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I have a chain where I do some blocking IO calls (e.g. HTTP-call). I want the blocking call to consume a value, proceed without interrupting, but drop everything that is piling up meanwhile, and then consume the next value in the same manner.

Consider the following example:

```
fun main() {
  Flowable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).onBackpressureLatest().map {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    it
  }.blockingForEach { println(it) }
}
```

From a naive point of view, I would it expect to print something like `0, 10, 20, ...`, but it prints `0, 1, 2, ...`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I thought about naively adding `debounce` to eat up the incoming stream:

```
fun main() {
  Flowable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .debounce(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .map {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      it
    }
    .blockingForEach { println(it) }
}
```

But, now I get a `java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted`.

EDIT:

What seems to work is the following:

```
fun main() {
  Flowable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .throttleLast(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .map {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      it
    }
    .blockingForEach { println(it) }
}
```

The output is as expected `0, 10, 20, ...`!!

Is that the correct way?

I noted that `throttleLast` will switch to the Computation-Scheduler. Is there a way to go back to the original scheduler?

EDIT:

I also get an occasional `java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted` with that variant.

Comment: Throttling can sometimes cancel the thread it is emitting on when the timer runs out before that thread finishes processing the previous throttled item. Add `observeOn` before the `map` to move the processing away from the throttler thread.

Comment: So throwing random exceptions is intended behavior?

Comment: Avoid blocking in the standard operators and you'll be fine.

Comment: Some third party code that uses locks/mutexes results in the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple approach to solve the problem is:

```
fun <T> Flowable<T>.lossy() : Flowable<T> {
  return onBackpressureLatest().observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1)
}
```

By calling `lossy` on a `Flowable` it starts to drop all element that are coming in faster than the downstream consumer can process.