# No `MissingBackpressureException` exception with `Flowable.interval` and blocking chain

Tags: rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

Consider the following example:

```
fun main() {
  Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    it
  }.blockingForEach { println(it) }
}
```

Do to missing backpressure, I would expect to get a `MissingBackpressureException` as written in the docs of `Flowable.interval`.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: By mapping the interval to sleep, you block the call stack so effectively you are producing one item per second, which can be easily processed by blockingForEach in time.

Comment: So I have to switch to another Scheduler before `map`. How do I get back to the previous scheduler after `map`?

Comment: You can only get back if you provide a custom one that uses the same worker thread. The standard schedulers besides `Schedulers.single()` don't help you with that, so you have to create one from an `ExecutorService` via `Schedulers.from()`. Why do you want to get an MBE in the first place?

Comment: I was researching a way to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606278/using-onbackpressurelatest-to-drop-intermediate-messages-in-blocking-flowable

Comment: @akarnokd Would you mind checking the other post, I am getting an `InterruptedException` with `debounce`.